# Documentation on Eclipse Monkey

Tags: javascript, eclipse, monkey

I'm looking for some documentation on "eclipse monkey" features.
What variables are predefined, what methods do these objects have and so on...

You can only get so far by tweaking the examples.

Comment: is there something to replace it?

Comment: Are you talking about http://sourceforge.net/projects/groovy-monkey/files/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eclipse Monkey](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Monkey_Overview) is listed as "past effort" for the [project Dash](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Dash_Project)

> Eclipse Monkey allows you to write scripts that run inside Eclipse and through DOMs are able to access and control(script) parts of the Eclipse Platform.
>   The Eclipse Monkey component of the Dash Project has been archived
>   This page is no longer actively maintained.

Yet you can find some documentation in this devx.com article:

[Enhance Eclipse RCP with Scripting](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/34545/1954)

[image: Scripting]

The merge between scripting languages and Eclipse goes through the definition of the com.devx.scripting plug-in.

Read also:
[Dynamic Scripting Lands in Europa: A Profile of Eclipse Monkey (cont'd)](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/35173/1763/page/2)

[image: Eclipse Monkey]

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Monkey API reference for the Editor panel: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Monkey/Javascript_Editor

Comment: I've created a blog post about it with more info links and also with my scripts repository: http://blog.millermedeiros.com/2010/02/eclipse-monkey-scripts-for-extending-aptana-and-eclipse-functionalities/